# Setting a CSS class based on a variable in Svelte

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

i am working on a custom component in Svelte and i want to be able to set the color with the help of corresponding identifiers(i callem types). For example success -> green, error -> red, etc.

Right now I am exporting a boolean for each of the "types" that can be set to true or false and therefore enables a class with the same name or not.

```
let success = false;
let error = false;
let info = false;
let warning = false; 
...
<div
    class:success
    class:error
    class:info
    class:warning >
</div>
```

This way the user would have to disable all but one of these types everytime he wants to change the type.

Is there a way i could do this similar like this almost pseudo code :D

```
export let type = "";
...
<div
    class:{type} >
</div>
```

So the User could then just use it the following way.

```
<custom-comp type={warning} />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
class={type}
```

instead of:

```
class:{type}
```

Comment: can be even shorter :) by removing the quotes: `class={type}`